# What does this number indicate in the name of this organic molecule?

Tags: nomenclature

When naming organic molecules, what does the 3 in front of the hexene indicate?

(E)-3-methyl-3-hexene

Comment: The name "hexene" is ambiguous on its own. (Why?)

Comment: So what does the 3 mean?

Comment: Location of the double bond.

Comment: We should actually write it as hex-3-ene, which allows beginners to understand nomenclature. The 3 shows the location of the double bond.

Comment: Also, the current IUPAC recommendations suggest hex-3-ene, too. 3-hexene was an old recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

The number ‘3’ is a locant. It designates an atom in the parent structure, for example to indicate the position of a substituent. Note that the preferred notation has changed in the past; hence, you can find different names in the literature:

- *trans*-3-methyl-3-hexene (1979)
- *trans*-3-methylhex-3-ene or (*E*)-3-methylhex-3-ene (1993)
- (3​*E*)-3-methylhex-3-ene (2013)

In the current version, locants are placed immediately before that part of the name to which they relate. This notation can be useful to avoid ambiguity.

In this case, 
‘3-methyl’ indicates the position of the methyl substituent, 
‘3-ene’ indicates the position of the double bond, and
‘3​*E*’ indicates the position of the stereogenic unit, which refers to the double bond that gives rise to *cis*-*trans* isomerism.

[image: (3​E)-3-methylhex-3-ene]

Note that, only the lower locant for the double bond is cited (i.e. ‘3’, not ‘3’ and ‘4’).

Without locants, the name ‘(*E*)-methylhexene’ would be ambiguous. For example, it could as well refer to (3​*E*)-2-methylhex-3-ene

[image: (3​E)-2-methylhex-3-ene]

or to (2​*E*)-3-methylhex-2-ene.

[image: (2​E)-3-methylhex-2-ene]